# Run Macro in Excel AFTER opening a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a Macro right after the Workbook opened as for some reasons the Macro requires the workbook to be opened before. `Workbook_activate` is not an option as the macro opens other files and therefore would result in an infinite loop.

The macro is working perfectly fine if i run it from the VBA-Editor, but it always throws

> Runtime Error 1004: The method `Cells` for the Object `_Global` has
>   failed

when i actually open the workbook.

This is the code im using:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call updateColumn("sheet", "Tabelle2", 1, 2)
  Call updateColumn("sheet", "Tabelle2", 5, 1)    
  Call updateSG("Tabelle2", "sheet")
End Sub
```

`updateColumn` updates the given column by opening another excel file and synchronizing the data from there. It works fine so i won't go into it here.

The Problem is always in the `updateSG` sub. It does basically the same as `updateColumn`, but it also iterates over the other file and sorts the required entries into corresponding columns.

```
Private Sub updateSG(sheetname As String, adbSheet As String)
Dim adb As Workbook
Dim report As Workbook
Dim row As Range
Dim fak As String
Dim N As Long
Dim rownumber As Long
Set report = Workbooks("thisfile.xlsm")
Set adb = Workbooks.Open(report.Path & "/ADB.xls")
rownumber = Cells(adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For i = 2 To rownumber
    fak = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value
    Select Case fak
        Case "E"
            N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row + 1
            report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(N, "C").Value = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 3)
        Case "G"
            N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row + 1
            report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(N, "D").Value = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 3)
        Case "I"
            N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row + 1
            report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(N, "E").Value = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 3)
        Case "M"
            N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row + 1
            report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(N, "F").Value = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 3)
        Case "P"
           N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row + 1
            report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(N, "G").Value = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 3)
        Case "T"
            N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row + 1
            report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(N, "H").Value = adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Cells(i, 3)
    End Select
Next
For i = 3 To 8
    report.Sheets(sheetname).Columns(i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
Next
Workbooks("ADB.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

End Sub

The issue is in the Line

```
rownumber = Cells(adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

and the lines from the select case going as

```
N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row + 1
```

These lines basically count the elements in a Column. Again, it works perfectly if i run it while the Workbook is open, but always throws the error when i actually open the file.

I hope someone here can help me.

Kind regards

Michael

Comment: `Cells` is not qualified to a specific workbook or worksheet. As such, it falls back to the global `Cells` which defaults to using the `Cells` object of *whatever worksheet is Active*. Failing to scope your objects properly is like the #1 cause of 1004 errors. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells` is not qualified to a specific workbook or worksheet. As such, it falls back to the global `Cells` which defaults to using the `Cells` object of *whatever worksheet is Active*. Failing to scope your objects properly is like the #1 cause of 1004 errors. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Change this:

```
Set adb = Workbooks.Open(report.Path & "/ADB.xls")
rownumber = Cells(adb.Sheets(adbSheet).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

Because in the above `Cells` statement, `Cells` refers to `ActiveSheet` (by default), which may or may not be the `adbSheet` name. If that sheet isn't active, error is expected.

To this, in order to ensure you've qualified `Cells` to the `adb` workbook object and `adbSheet` worksheet.

```
Set adb = Workbooks.Open(report.Path & "/ADB.xls")
With adb.Sheets(adbSheet)
    rowNumber = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The rownumber now works, but the error now pops up in thte  `N = report.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row + 1` and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it here as it is supposed to only count the entries in column "E".

Comment: The nature of both problems is the same. You have `Rows.Count` again which is not qualified to a particular worksheet.

Comment: `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, `Range`, etc., these are all child-objects/properties of a `Worksheet`, and if you're not explicitly assigning them against a specific worksheet, Excel will always interpret them impicitly as `ActiveSheet.<property>`, which is prone to failure for a number of reasons, in this case you're trying to define a range that spans multiple sheets -- which is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it out. it works perfectly now.